# xjc generates different code for optional elements when using element ref

Tags: xml, xsd, xjc

I have the following schema which, as I understand it, declares the element `<foo>` which has two optional elements `<bar>` and `<baz>` of type nillable string.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" nillable="true" />

  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="bar" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

When I run the schema through `xjc`, the output is as follows.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "bar",
    "baz"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected String bar;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "baz", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> baz;

    // getters and setters as you'd expect
}
```

Notice how `bar` has not been generated as `JAXBElement<String>` even though it is both nillable and optional.  Is this a bug in xjc?  How am I supposed to differentiate between these two documents?

```
<foo>
  <baz>hello world</baz>
</foo>

<foo>
  <bar xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  <baz>hello world</baz>
</foo>
```

Comment: I think that the scope of the elements is different. `<baz>` can be added only under` <foo>`, for this reason has been added `nillable = true` instead of `JAXBElement<String>`.  If you see ObjectFactory there will be `createFooBaz` and `createBar`. An Option could be avoid that `ref`.

Comment: Indeed, however I would like to use `ref` because it allows me to declare the element globally and reuse it in different places but with different `minOccurs` attributes, e.g.: declare `<foo2>` which has `<xs:element ref="bar" minOccurs="2"/>`